# error JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly

Tags: java, linux, centos7

When Ii run command mvn spring-boot:run, I got error:

```
JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64/bin/java
```

when I check above path java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.el7_3.x86_64 
is not exist.

My java version is:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_161"
```

I check JAVA_HOME in /etc/environment

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre
```

Is it because of different version in JAVA_HOME I got the error?
I try to change the JAVA_HOME path to other version but still got same error.
I'm using centos 7.

Comment: what's `java -version` output?

Comment: what's `echo $JAVA_HOME` output?

Comment: @TaherKhorshidi java version is 1.8.0_161 java home is /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.131-3.b12.e17_3.x86_64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved when i run this command

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

Answer (score 0):

> CentOS

The "select a java version command" is

```
# /usr/sbin/alternatives --config java
```